Proof: Show that $\bar{d}_j = 2 \text{var}_j$
I have constructed a proof to show that $\bar{d}_j = 2 \text{var}_j$ in the equation below, and I am in need of some input on the proof I have established. I will state the problem, provide my solution, and then ask my questions at the very end.
Problem:
Show that $\bar{d}_j = 2\text{var}_j$ in the following equation:
$$
\bar{d}_j = \frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i'=1}^N (x_{ij} - x_{i'j})^2,
$$
where $\text{var}_j$ is the sample estimate of the variance of $X_j$.
Proof:
We start by expanding the squared difference:
$$
(x_{ij} - x_{i'j})^2 = x_{ij}^2 - 2x_{ij}x_{i'j} + x_{i'j}^2,
$$
which gives us the following:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i'=1}^N (x_{ij} - x_{i'j})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i'=1}^N \left( x_{ij}^2 - 2x_{ij}x_{i'j} + x_{i'j}^2 \right).
$$
This can be further simplified to:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i'=1}^N (x_{ij} - x_{i'j})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i'=1}^N x_{ij}^2 - 2 \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i'=1}^N x_{ij} x_{i'j} + \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i'=1}^N x_{i'j}^2.
$$
Now, using the identities:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i'=1}^N x_{ij}^2 = N \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2, \quad \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i'=1}^N x_{i'j}^2 = N \sum_{i=1}^N x_{i'j}^2,
$$
and
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i'=1}^N x_{ij} x_{i'j} = \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} \right)^2,
$$
we can insert these into the expression for $\bar{d}_j$:
$$
\bar{d}_j = \frac{1}{N^2} \left[ N \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2 - 2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} \right)^2 + N \sum_{i=1}^N x_{i'j}^2 \right].
$$
Combining terms and simplifying, we get:
$$
\bar{d}_j = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2 - \frac{2}{N^2} \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_{i'j}^2.
$$
Since $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_{i'j}^2$, we can further simplify to:
$$
\bar{d}_j = \frac{2}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2 - \frac{2}{N^2} \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} \right)^2.
$$
Now, recall the formula for variance:
$$
\text{var}_j = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_{ij} - \bar{x}_j)^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2 - \bar{x}_j^2,
$$
where $\bar{x}_j = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}$.
Substitute $\bar{x}_j^2 = \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} \right)^2$, we get:
$$
\text{var}_j = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2 - \frac{1}{N^2} \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} \right)^2.
$$
Finally, we see that:
$$
\bar{d}_j = 2 \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2 - \frac{1}{N^2} \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} \right)^2 \right) = 2 \, \text{var}_j.
$$
Thus, we have shown that:
$$
\bar{d}_j = 2 \, \text{var}_j.
$$
Questions:

Is it correct to use this form of variance? The problem states that $\text{var}_j$ is the sample estimate of the variance of $X_j$, so should I use divition by $N-1$ instead of $N$? Do we really get the correct answer then?
Is it valid to assume that $\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{i'=1}^N x_{ij} x_{i'j} = \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} \right)^2$?

Extra information: In detail, this is how I extended the variance function for those who are interested:
Start with the definition of the sample variance:
$$
\text{var}_j = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_{ij} - \bar{x}_j)^2
$$
Now, expand the squared difference:
$$
= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \left( x_{ij}^2 - 2x_{ij} \bar{x}_j + \bar{x}_j^2 \right)
$$
Separate the summation:
$$
= \frac{1}{N} \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2 - 2 \bar{x}_j \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} + \sum_{i=1}^N \bar{x}_j^2 \right)
$$
Since $ \bar{x}_j $ is a constant, simplify:
$$
= \frac{1}{N} \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2 - 2 \bar{x}_j \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} + N \bar{x}_j^2 \right)
$$
Substitute $ \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij} = N \bar{x}_j $:
$$
= \frac{1}{N} \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2 - 2N \bar{x}_j^2 + N \bar{x}_j^2 \right)
$$
Combine like terms:
$$
= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2 - \bar{x}_j^2
$$
Thus, we have:
$$
\text{var}_j = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (x_{ij} - \bar{x}_j)^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ij}^2 - \bar{x}_j^2.
$$
